# Why I need to add an extra parenthesis for sum() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

if `sum()` is a function in python, why does it need an extra parenthesis to work? Like other functions why `sum()` is not working with single parenthesis?

It's not working when it's like this:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())

total = sum(num1, num2)

print(total)
```

It is working fine when I'm adding an extra parenthesis. Why this is happening?

```
total = sum((num1, num2))
```

Comment: The second parameter to sum is the start value. The first parameter needs to be an iterable and a single integer is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sum` function in python takes in a `tuple` or a `list` of numbers as the first parameter ( because it should be iterable) and returns the sum of the elements.

[Check this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
sum ( num1, num2,...) #Gives Type Error since int is non iterable
sum ((num1,num2,...)) #works
sum([num1,num2,...] #works
```

Answer (score 0):

in python, the sum() function takes as parameter an iterable, its actual function is tu sum the elements in a list, library or tuple. So, in your code what you are actually doing is creating a tuple with `num1` & `num2` in it and passing it as a parameter un the sum() function.

Answer (score 0):

Python sum() is an inbuilt function that takes an iterable and returns the sum of items in it. The iterable may be Python list, tuple, set, or dictionary. The sum () function adds the elements of an iterable and returns the sum. Here you are passing a tuple with number values and pass the tuple as a parameter to sum() function, and in return, you will get the sum of tuple items.